# Gimp, script that iterates through several images and exports each one with different options

Tags: gimp, export, script

I'm quite new to gimp. Assuming I have N images I was wondering if it is possible do the following:

```
For i = 1...N
  For each export options j = 1 .. N
      Export(img[i],option[j]);
```

Basically what I'm doing manually is to load an image and export it using the following dialog:

[image]

where (for example) I set different compressions level at each export, or changing 8bpc RGBA to (for example) 16bpc RGB etc.

Also I'd like to repeat the same iteration but maybe for jpeg for example, with other options etc.

Is there a way to script the whole process over a set of say 100 images?

Comment: Yes... if I understand that what you want to do is export several instances of the same image with different options and repeat this over a  whole set of images. The script remains to be written. But maybe you want [this](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/03/google-jpeg-guetzli-encoder-file-size/)

Comment: What's that in a nutshell?

Comment: Also what do I need to do to write the script? I mean can the necessaries functionalities I would need to use from gimp be available to be used from a command line? (So maybe I can write a shell script that does everything I need).

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44435560/6378557) for an example of batch processing in Gimp. But unless you are testing Gimp image encoding, it would be easier with [ImageMagicks's `convert`](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) in a shell script.

Comment: I'm using ImageMagick right now (amazing), but for sake of knowledge I'll leave the question open,